# Haxe IntelliJ / VSCode generated SWFs not recognised

Tags: flash, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, haxe, openfl

I've set up SWF libraries in my current IntelliJ IDEA `project.xml` with `preload` / `generate` / `embed` all set to `true`. I can instantiate the class in code and everything works when I test the project but IntelliJ calls it an "unresolved symbol". I tried adding the assets folder as a library source in my module (tried the SWC too) but nothing works. Am I doing something wrong or is this beyond IntelliJ's capabilities?

**Edit**: after being recommended VSCode I got my project set up in that IDE as well. I'm having the same issue, except VSCode cancels the build even though OpenFL returns no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct solution but I built through OpenFL and pointed IntelliJ at the created `/Export/flash/haxe/_generated/` directory and it worked. It looks like it would work for VSCode too.

Something doesn't seem right about it, though. like my SWF refs are of my previous build but everything else reflects the next build

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend switching to a simpler editor, I would suggest
Visual Studio Code because it works on win/linux/mac.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadako.vshaxe

But there are other options
If you are on windows only then HaxeDevelop ( FlashDevelop ) is very good.
https://haxedevelop.org/
Atom possibly, especially if you use Luxe.
https://github.com/snowkit/atom-haxe/tree/haxe-rewrite
Vim if your that way inclined and like keystrokes.
https://github.com/jdonaldson/vaxe
Or just any nice simple text editor ( I often use textmate ) with terminal.

I would not touch Intellij or FDT for developing Haxe I have tried pretty much every editor with support for Haxe, and these two were a mess, I am sure they are good for AS3, java and the like but not for Haxe. I am told they have improved a lot but I would still stay well clear.

My reasoning is that they are very complex products and there are not enough Haxe users for these companies to invest in the support needed for a complex ecosystem like Haxe, also Haxe is evolving fast and it is hard for them to keep up with new features even though haxe complier offers so much completion support.  Most Haxe users have learnt to avoid power ides apart from a few in large companies who can assist each other with setup issues.

Your much better off just going for Visual Studio Code or Kode ( Kha version ), as it seems to be now the preferred option for Haxe development and it's free, and most people on gitter or irc can help.

Sorry if I am not able to answer your problem but if you continue to use a power IDE like intellij you will be back with more problems, so save yourself the pain and just switch to Visual Studio Code and terminal, and if your still having issues then you will get plenty of help.

Comment: I downloaded visual studio code yesterday, and I'm trying to learn it, and nothing makes sense yet in terms of project set up. I'm on a mac, btw. I have haxedevelop on the PC I never touch and it's truly amazing.

Back to the issue at hand, I just really don't want to switch IDE's on a week long project, and I'm still not convinced that this is something that intelli-j cant do. but yeah, i am really sick of it

Comment: got the project working in vscode, having the same issue.